# Cant login to FB Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

Wow, FB SDK su*** big time.
I've been spending way too much time trying to figure out why a simple login wont work.
The "HelloFacebookSample" works fine and logs into FB using my account but when I try to implement it in my app I get nothing!

I actually copy-pasted almost the entire Activity they wrote just to see if it will work, why did they do it so cumbersome?

When I print out the "session" this is what I get:

```
08-03 17:49:02.074: D/SESSION(30213): {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:
```

Basically, I have the "log in with Facebook button" set up and when I click on it it tries to connect but with no success.

Here is the activity:

```
public class FacebookLogin extends Activity {

    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private Button postPhotoButton;
    private Button pickFriendsButton;
    private Button pickPlaceButton;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    private ViewGroup controlsContainer;
    private GraphUser user;
    private GraphPlace place;
    private List<GraphUser> tags;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,
        POST_PHOTO,
        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.fb_login);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);



    loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            FacebookLogin.this.user = user;
            updateUI();
            // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to be populated in order to post a
            // status update.
           // handlePendingAction();
        }
    });

    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);



    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if(session==null){
            session = new Session.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setApplicationId(getString(R.string.app_id)).build();
        }
        session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Log.d("SESSION", session+"");

       // Log.d("SESSION", session.toString()+"");
        boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());
        Log.d("SESSION_BOOL", enableButtons+"");


        if (enableButtons && user != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
            greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, user.getFirstName()));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
        String getId();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE &&
                (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(FacebookLogin.this)
                    .setTitle("Cancel")
                    .setMessage("Permissions not granted")
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
        updateUI();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

    }


}
```

Added into Manifest:

```
  <meta-data
       android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
       android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Please help me understand what am I missing?

Comment: Why did you censor 'sucks'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

also you need to add the list of permission when you press the login button

```
public static final List<String> PERMISSION = Arrays.asList("email",
            "public_profile");

loginButton.setReadPermissions(PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution. Now that I'm "connected", how do I keep the session alive between my app components? if I write "finish()" on this activity I immediately see the login button back to it's original state and the session is then closed.

How would I pass the open session around?